# Deleting Excel ListObject after Unlisting it

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm doing a VSTO add-in project in C#.

Basically, I want to retrieve data from a database and put it to excel. However, I just want do write the data in the format of a simple range and dont keep any kind of binding to the datasource.

To do it, I'm creating a ListObject and setting its datasource to a datatable populated with the data. Then, I'm calling the method Unlist to convert the table back to a normal range and them I'm trying to remove the listobject from the worksheet so I can use the same listobject name when I repeat this process.

The problem is that when i try to delete the listobject C# is throwing a bad index exception.

Here is the code:

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;

    Worksheet extendedWorksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(worksheet);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cell = extendedWorksheet.Application.ActiveCell;
    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject listObject;
    BindingSource bindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource();
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;
    listObject = extendedWorksheet.Controls.AddListObject(cell, "list1");
    listObject.AutoSetDataBoundColumnHeaders = true;
    listObject.SetDataBinding(bindingSource, "");
    listObject.Unlist();
    extendedWorksheet.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
```

I also tried some variations to remove the listobject, but none of them worked:

```
extendedWorksheet.Controls.Remove("list1');
//or
listObject.Delete()
//or
foreach (ListObject x in extendedWorksheet.Controls)
{
    x.Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

foreach (ListObject x in extendedWorksheet.ListObject**s**)